# Delete class and objects during migration

Tags: ios, realm

Right now I have two data models:

```
class Habit: Object{
     ...
     ...

     dynamic var owner: HabitList?
}

class HabitList: Object{

    dynamic var habits = List<Habit>()
}
```

I want to delete `HabitList` class and `owner` of `Habit` class, I'm not really sure I understand how to use `delete` and `deleteData` and what is a `MigrationObject`. Do I need to use `migration.enumerate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

If you want to completely delete the data inside `HabitList` and the `owner` object, then there's very little you need to do. :)

Firstly, simply delete the `owner` object and `HabitList` class definitions to remove them from your project. After that, as of Realm 0.95 (That we released last week. I recommend upgrading if you haven't already!), there's a new way to handle migrations:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
   //You need to increment the version everytime you change your object schema (starts at 0)
   schemaVersion: 1, 
   migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
      //If you want to preserve any data, you can do it here, otherwise just leave it blank.
   }
)

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = Realm() //The database will now be migrated!
```

All you need to do is create a Realm configuration object, set a new schema version (To let Realm know you've changed your objects' schema) and then specify a migration block (Which you can leave empty if you don't want to keep any of the information in the properties you've deleted), and then pass the configuration object to Realm. Realm will then automatically update your Realm file with the new schema the next time you call `Realm()`.

There's more information on the [Realm docs page](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations). Let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes total sense now.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you take a look at this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419664/realm-not-working-after-migration/32428779#32428779

Comment: 2019-08-20 This solution no longer appears to work. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571473/drop-a-table-in-a-realmswift-migration/57581869#57581869) as it does work.