# Drop a table in a RealmSwift migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am removing an old unused table from the schema. How can I delete it (DROP Table) from older versions of the app? What I have tried so far

1. Removed `GameScore.self` from `configration.objectTypes`
2. Bumped schema version
3. Run the app
4. Opened Realm Studio and the table GameScore is still there with the data that was already there previously

Adding

```
config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 10 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "GameScore", { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    if let oldObject = oldObject {
                        migration.delete(oldObject)
                    }

                })
            }

        }
```

Will remove all the data from GameScore. I still don't get why realm doesn't remove the GameScore table completely (I can still see it with Realm Studio)

Answer (score 0):

To completely delete a table (called CLASS in realm terms) one needs to do the following:

```
 config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 10 {
                migration.deleteData(forType: "GameScore")
            }

        }
```

My initial solution

```
config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 10 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "GameScore", { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    if let oldObject = oldObject {
                        migration.delete(oldObject)
                    }

                })
            }

        }
```

Will only delete the contents of that table, it clears out the data but doesn't remove the table from the db.

Comment: lol. Well, I answered this earlier and forgot to post it and as soon as I did I saw you found the answer. I added a little more context in my answer but this was a good find as the prior methods don't seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a table would be the same as deleting a Realm Object from a Realm and all of it's data.

If that's the case, there's no need for iteration. In your migration block just use [deleteData(forType:)](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration6deleteFCS_13DynamicObjectT_)

> Deletes the data for the class with the given name.
>
> All objects of the given class will be deleted. If the Object subclass
>   no longer exists in your program, any remaining metadata for the class
>   will be removed from the Realm file.

Three steps

1) Remove the Realm Object class from your code

2) Increment the schemaVersion in your migration block. This notifies realm there's a new schema

3) Delete the object and it's data within the migration block by using a string of it's name.

Suppose we are working on schema version 1 and have a TestClass Realm object we want to get rid of. Remove the class from your code, increment to schema 2 and use deleteData

```
let config = Realm.Configuration (
    schemaVersion: 2,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        migration.deleteData(forType: "TestClass")
})
```