# Realm Migration Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, migration, realm

I added a new Class ,`newClass`, to my Realm file through Realm Studio to allow users to manage an array of items. I also created swift file to manage the new class in XCode.

Since running the app immediately after doing the above, all my data from the `firstClass`, has disappeared (not a problem the user adds all data in this class on startup, I can repopulate whilst testing the app.)

My app now crashes whenever it reaches any code `let realm = try! Realm()`. I have commented out or removed references to these to see if it is a localised problem, but it still continuous to crash with the following similar errors depending on the VC it crashes on when during `let realm = try! Realm()`.

```
schema version 1
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1., Error Code=1}: file /Users/UserName/Desktop/AppName/AppName/Custom VC's/AddDataToRealmViewController.swift, line 168

2020-06-27 13:23:10.481817+0100 AppName[4498:173994] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1., Error Code=1}: file /Users/UserName/Desktop/AppName/AppName/Custom VC's/AddDataToRealmViewController.swift, line 168
```

After doing a little bit of reading around, it suggest I need to migrate my realm file to the new schema? Before I attempt this, would this be the correct course of action to take?

Comment: Well, that error indicates you've added a property to a Realm object and therefore you need to migrate your data using a [migration block](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#local-migrations) and update the version number. There may also some component of needing to update your API as well, but for the moment, the migration is required.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I've performed the migration successfully. Viewing the Realm file in Realm Studio, I can see the class I created manually in the Studio still there alongside the class that was created in Xcode and the `newClass` VC. 1. Would I delete the class through another migration code? 2. Would you recommend I comment out the migration code in AppDelegate, or leave it as the code wont run as the new schema is = 1?

Comment: It's going to depend on your use case. For us during development, we just erase the whole Realm and start fresh so we don't need to worry about versioning. 1) If you want to remove the class, do it during the [Migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFT7forTypeSS_Sb) using deleteData(forType:), keeping in mind any references to that object should be removed from code. 2) Depends on the use case. During development or not and local realm or sync'd realm as sync'd realms don't use migration blocks.

Comment: I will try deleteData(forType: unwantedClass). Would I put it `migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    // HERE?
                }

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571473/drop-a-table-in-a-realmswift-migration/57581869#57581869) for some more reading. So probably yes, but it depends on what else is going on within the migration.